# YouTube download link generator in Python

Tags: python, youtube

How to convert something like

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYffV7qhvTc
```

into something like
    http://something.flv [the downloadable file of corresponding video]

in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/). On the command line:

```
youtube-dl -g http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYffV7qhvTc
```

If you want it in pure Python, have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube-dl) and call `download` with the appropriate setup.

Comment: I have a script which generates the youtube link
How can I supply that link to youtube-dl as a command line argument?

Comment: @meadhikari Updated the answer. You can use the `subprocess` module if you want to call youtube-dl on the command line.

Comment: @meadhikari `stdout,stderr=subprocess.Popen(['youtube-dl', '-g', url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()`. After that, `flvUrl = stdout.strip()`.

Comment: @phihag is there any fix to "Access denied" problem caused when using the download url somewhere else, or is it the youtube problem?

Comment: @meadhikari I can reproduce the problem (I get "403 Forbidden" when I try to download with another program). You can either let `youtube-dl` do the downloading itself (just remove the `-g` argument) or try to reproduce the same request from the same IP by reading the cookies stored with `--cookies=cookiefile`.

Comment: @phihag i need to download it using a download manager so removing -g is not a option, so what exactly must I do to "reproduce the same request from the same IP by reading the cookies stored with --cookies=cookiefile"

Comment: @meadhikari Most likely, having the cookies is enough. `youtube-dl` can save the cookies it receives from youtube via the `--cookie` option. You need to read these cookies with `cookielib.FileCookieJar` and then advise your download manager to use them. If that doesn't work, youtube can only filter by other HTTP headers, like `User-Agent`. You can find out what exactly youtube-dl and your application use with a suitable network traffic dumping tool such as wireshark.

Comment: @phihag: I just want to say thankyou. That advice was exactly what I needed to feed the output of the youtube-dl --cookie option into the wget --load-cookies option. Thanks again!